# how to get the last login time for all users in one line for different shells

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh, csh

I can make the following line work on ksh

```
for user in $( awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd); do last $user | head -1 ; done | tr -s "\n" |sort
```

But I'd like to make it work on UNIX sh and UNIX csh. (in linux sh it runs fine, but linux is not unix...)

I know there are limitations for this since it seems that each UNIX(*) has its own variations on the syntax.

update: sorry, there are some restrictions here:

1. I can't write on the disk, so I can't save scripts.
2. how do i write this in CSH?

Comment: do everything in one language, e.g. awk, python, perl etc.

Comment: You broken into a box which only has `csh` and you don't want to fix it for the legitimate owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk-script seems to be the  equivalent to you loop above:

```
{
  cmd = "last "$1
  cmd | getline result
  printf "%s",  result
}
```

use it like this:

```
awk -F: -f script_above.awk /etc/passwd
```

Pipe the output to `sort`

As a one-liner:

```
$ awk -F: '{cmd = "last "$1; cmd | getline result;printf "%s", result}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I can't write on disk. sorry

Comment: thanks. I am still dealing with the fact that the machine does not have getline :-( but it's a pretty elegant solution. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This might do the trick for you, should be POSIX compliant:

```
last | awk 'FNR==NR{split($0,f,/:/);a[f[1]];next}($1 in a)&&++b[$1]==1' /etc/passwd - |  sort
```

Comment: This is actually shell agnostic; should work in any popular Unix shell, and several impopular.

Comment: @tripleee that's what I was going for ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need Awk for this.

```
while IFS=: read user _; do
    last "$user" | head -n 1
done </etc/passwd  # | grep .
```

Instead of reinvent it in Csh, how about

```
sh -c 'while IFS=: read user _; do last "$user" | head -n 1; done </etc/passwd'
```

You will get empty output for users who have not logged in since `wtmp` was rotated; maybe add a `| grep .` to weed those out.  (I added it commented out above.)

To reiterate, `IFS=:` sets the shell's internal field separator to a colon, so that `read` will split the password file on that.

Comment: thanks but the problem is exactly I don't have other shell than csh :-(

Comment: Serious? Even if the default shell is Csh, you would be hard pressed to find a box where `/bin/sh` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple command:

```
lastlog
```